# Increasing the size of casper-rw file system for USB installation of Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

USB flashdrive install of a live-linux distribution using a casper-rw filesystem. Both the Windows and Ubuntu installation programs to install a downloaded ISO file to the USB stick use a casper-rw filesystem limited to at most 4Gb. That is too small for the kind of installation (Ubuntu+TeX-live). Is there a way to increase the size of the casper-rw filesystem? The USB stick has plenty of room (16Gb total size).

Comment: I believe that's a limitation of fat32. Would a solution that enables you to have this software into the readonle part of the liveusb to maximise space on the persistent part of the drive be ok.?

Answer (score 2):

This link is a link to a tutorial on how to increase Casper - rw size , http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-create-a-larger-casper-rw-loop-file/

I hope it helps

Comment: Please summarize, the link might go away.